# NullReferenceException while reading the description of the event log using System.Management class

Tags: vb.net, event-log

I am able to query/read the event log using VB.NET 2005 (Win XP). But still I have a problem reading the "Message" / "description" of the event log.

I am getting a System.NullReferenceException while reading the "Message" / "Description" of the event log.

Also when I use System.Diagnostics.EventLog and read all the Event on by one I am able to read the message/description of the event.

This is the code:

```
Public Sub ReadEvent()
    Dim iCount As Int16
    Dim PastFourHours As Date = Date.Now.AddHours(-4)
    Dim sQuery As String = "Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile = 'MyLogFile' AND TimeGenerated > '" & PastFourHours.ToString() & "'"

    Dim myConnectionOptions As New System.Management.ConnectionOptions
    Dim myManagementScope As System.Management.ManagementScope
    Dim myObjectSearcher As System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
    Dim colLoggedEvents As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection
    Dim objEvent As System.Management.ManagementObject

    With myConnectionOptions
        .Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
        .Authentication = System.Management.AuthenticationLevel.Packet
    End With

    myManagementScope = New System.Management.ManagementScope("\\.\root\cimv2", myConnectionOptions)
    myManagementScope.Connect()                         'connect to WMI namespace

    If (Not myManagementScope.IsConnected) Then
        Call PrintLogToAFile("Could not connect to WMI namespace")
    End If

    myObjectSearcher = New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(myManagementScope.Path.ToString, sQuery.ToString())
    colLoggedEvents = myObjectSearcher.Get()               'execute query

    For Each objEvent In colLoggedEvents
        Call PrintLogToAFile("Category: " + objEvent("Category").ToString())                           
        Call PrintLogToAFile("Message: " + objEvent("Message").ToString())
        Call PrintLogToAFile("Type: " + objEvent("Type").ToString())                                   

        iCount = iCount + 1
    Next

    Call PrintLogToAFile("Number of records: " + iCount.ToString())
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:** It only occurs on each item of "Message" in the loop while it is getting the other items. Also indeed there is an element keyed as "Message" in the objEvent as per the event log structure given under

```
//Event Log structure:
uint16 Category;
string CategoryString;
string ComputerName;
uint8 Data[];
uint16 EventCode;
uint32 EventIdentifier;
uint8 EventType;
string InsertionStrings[];
string Logfile;
string Message;
uint32 RecordNumber;
string SourceName;
datetime TimeGenerated;
datetime TimeWritten;
string Type;
string User;
```

This is the full stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="WindowsApplication1"
  StackTrace:
       at WindowsApplication1.GlobalMod.ReadEvent() in G:\WindowsApplication1\GlobalMod.vb:line 88
       at WindowsApplication1.Form1.BtnRead_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in G:\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line 11
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say, if you get so far as to call `objEvent("Message")`, that such an element keyed as `Message` is not available in `objEvent` for at least one of the items. Does this occur on each item in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous usage (I was doing the same thing in C#) Message can be null, you need to test for that.